# Build and deploy apache-superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to build superset from source on a linux box (debian). 
The goal is to deploy it on a web server (apache2 for example) .

Is it at all possible to deploy as a standalone webapplication on a web server without using the "python setup.py install" command ?

If not, I have tried building it as suggested on this page :  https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#making-your-own-build
But encountered the following error :

> Installed
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy_Utils-0.33.3-py2.7.egg
>   error: The 'sqlalchemy' distribution was not found and is required by
>   superset

Should i be installing any SQLAlchemy packages before perfoming the superset installation ?

Comment: What version of Superset are you trying to install? I would suggest installing using pip.

Comment: @Climbs_lika_Spyder, He is getting the error while building the sourcecode.

Comment: Try `pip install -r requirements.txt` before `setup.py` for some reason the new install method doesn't install dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install -r requirements.txt` before `setup.py` for some reason the new install method doesn't install dependencies correctly.